# How to merge 2 files and group their lines based on first number

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I have 2 files:

```
1 "aaa"
2 "bbb"
4 "ddd"
3 "ccc"
```

and

```
1 "111"
3 "333"
4 "444"
```

How can I merge into one file using bash to look exactly like this:

```
file1 "1 "aaa""
file2 "1 "111""

file1 "2 "bbb""
file2 ""

file1 "3 "ccc""
file2 "3 "333""

file1 "4 "ddd""
file2 "4 "444""
```

I was thinking about using arrays, however so far, I managed to find only arrays who would parse and sort the whole line.

I need grouping just based on the first number.

Also, I want to be able to add some text to the file.

So far I have this script:

```
exec 6<"key-value-strings-utf8-preklad.txt"
while read -r line
do
    read -r f2line <&6
    echo "msgid \"${line}\""
    echo "msgstr \"${f2line}\""
    echo ""
done <"key-value-strings-utf8.txt"
exec 6<&-
```

Problem is, that it requires both files to be sorted exactly the same.

Do you have any clues?

My intention is to merge 2 files (one in English and one in Czech) and create gettext po file from them so that I can work on translation to help some people (a bit complicated explanation but so far seems to be best option for me).

Unfortunatelly gettext tools won't help because they wrap lines (even when using --no-wrap, then messages are wrapped after /n)  and I need them unwrapped.

Thank you.

Comment: just use `msginit --no-translator --locale=cz.UTF-8 --output-file=cz.po --input=en_source.pot ` - and you will get an `.po` file (with english texts - generated from the original `pot` file) and you can replace the english text directly with czech, without the need of "merge"... Later for the "updates" you could use `msgmerge --sort-output --update cz.po en_source.pot`.

Comment: Hello. I don't have source pot file. I have just original file and translation file. I wanted to merge them together to make translation easier for me. Usage of gettext is not a way for me as those tend to wrap lines (even when using - - no-wrap). I mentioned the purpose because I wanted to show, I'm not asking for personal benefit but to help others

Comment: Welcome here. Regardless of your good intentions, this site is about helping for programmers, and not a free code writing service. :) So, you will get more correct answers if  you shows some your own effort - what do you tried. Please read [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Combine the files with filenames using awk, then sort appropriately:

```
awk '{print ARGV[ARGIND]": "$0}' file1 file2 | sort -k 2n -k 1,1
```

This will not insert the blanks for "missing" matches, but you can figure that out.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Thank you for showing the way.

Answer (score 0):

If whitespace and order within each index isn't important, the `sort` should be up to the task.

`cat file1 file2 | sort`

...will give you:

```
 1 "111"
 1 "aaa"
 2 "bbb"
 3 "333"
 3 "ccc"
 4 "444"
 4 "ddd"
```

If you do need a blank line between indices, or you need to preserve order within each index,

Something like

```
x=1
while [ $x -lt 9999 ]; do
  (cat file1 file2 | grep "^$x" && echo) | tee -a file3
  x=$((x+1))
done
```

will give you:

```
1 "aaa"
1 "111"

2 "bbb"

3 "ccc"
3 "333"

4 "ddd"
4 "444"
```

Comment: Actually, I need it to look like in that example.

Maybe if I edit it in a way:
<code>
    x=1
    while [ $x -lt 9999 ]; do
      (echo "file1 "$(cat file1)" ; echo "file2 "$(cat file2)" | grep "^$x" && echo) | tee -a file3
      x=$((x+1))
    done

Comment: Including the "file 1" part? And the nested, unescaped double quotes?

Comment: Yes. Those are there on purpose.

Comment: BTW, what is file3 supposed to be? Output? Because it is empty at the end and cat is printed on the screen.